# Meteor 0.8 - All HTML must be inside templates now?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I had an app using Bootstrap & Iron Router and had my navbar code outside of the {{yield}}.. eg:

```
<body>
 <nav class...>
  <div class="navbar-container">
   ....
  </div>
 </nav>
 {{>yield}}
</body>
```

After I upgraded to Meteor 0.8 my navbar disappeared until I put it into a template that was in {{yield}}... is this supposed to happen? Am I supposed to be using layout templates now?

Thanks!

Comment: I've heard that in the new templates it is illegal to fragment a block element.  That is, you can't have `<template><div> {> something} </template>.....</div>`

Comment: that's not what I have though.. there's no templates within that <nav class>

Comment: Are you aware of this link -- I got it a mass email from the Meteor team today.... https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Comment: yup, got that email too, can't find anything in there or the wiki about not being able to have HTML outside of a template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation on [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#layouts--rendering):

> By default, the router renders the current template directly into the body. If you'd like to share common HTML between routes, you can create your own layout:

Since you don't have a layout defined, you are applying this default and the template is being rendered in the body tags.

So you empty the body tags and make you code into a template:

```
<template name="layout">
  <nav class...>
    <div class="navbar-container">
      ....
    </div>
  </nav>
  {{>yield}}
</template>
```

and then define a default layout in you client side js.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
})
```

Comment: so is this new? pre 0.8 my code above worked...

when it says "By default, the router renders the current template directly into the body.." does that mean it overwrites whatever is there?

Comment: Yes, it renders the template to the <body> tags rather than the {{> yield}}.  If you want to use {{> yield}} then define a layout.